# ASP Core how to use anchor tag helper with Get action?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, webserver, url-routing

How do I generate a url like this "www.example.com/cars/1/slug" using anchor tag helper?

```
[Route("cars")]
 public class CarsController: Controller
   {
   [HttpGet("{id}/{slug?}")]
 public IActionResult Get(int id, string slug = "static-slug")
    {
           ...
```

In my razor view I wrote this:

```
    <a  asp-controller="cars"  asp-route-id="@ResultSearch.CarId" asp-route-slug="@ResultSearch.Slug">
```

generates this

```
http://example.com/cars/cars?id=1072&slug=slug
```

I'm following more or less the restful design I can't name the Get action "cars" because I've already defined another route with this name, to display the cars section. The route I am working on is to display the details of a particular car.

Comment: Have you tried to add `asp-action="Get"`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the action, it can't find the action unless it's there:

```
<a asp-action="Get" asp-controller="Cars" asp-route-id="@ResultSearch.CarId" asp-route-slug="@ResultSearch.Slug">
```

Comment: I would end up with this: www.example.com/cars/get/1/slug I want this www.example.com/cars/1/slug. The get would break the "friendly url" perfectionism. I don't buy this thing of "friendly url" but it seems to me that most of the web developers agreed with this idea. friendly urls give the opportunity to generate fake urls to products that doesn't exist so they get a result on Google and display a similar product but not the one that the "friendly url" described Ebay uses it a lot!

Comment: You should not have `get` in the URL. For me the link becomes `http://localhost:33215/cars/1072/some-slug`. You need to specify the action so that it can find the action that you want to link to. It then uses the stuff you defined in attributes to generate the URL.